# Using for loop to seperate formsets with <hr> only between forms and not at beginning or end

Tags: python, django

I only want the horizontal rule between each form and not at the beginning or end.
How can I alter the code so that the last horizontal rule is removed and how many different ways are there to doing this?

```
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for form in formset %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <hr>
  {% endfor %}
  <button type="submit">Add Family Members</button>
</form>
```

Here's another example:

```
mylist = ['Tom', 'John', 'Jack', 'Joe']
for i in mylist:
    print(i)
    print('----------')
```

How can I alter the code so that '--------' is printed between the names but not at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Django template the usual method is to test the [`forloop.first`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for) or `forloop.last` variables the template engine exposes during the loop.

EG

```
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for form in formset %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% if not forloop.last %}
  <hr>
  {% endif} %}
  {% endfor %}
  <button type="submit">Add Family Members</button>
</form>
```

In plain Python code I'd try to use `join` for the specific case of using a delimiter to combine elements of an iterable. In the general case I can't think of an alternative to maintaining state yourself, eg a boolean indicating whether this is the first iteration of the loop or using `enumerate` and testing the index. Or just executing once outside the loop if you're sure your iterable is non-empty and then looping.

`join` returns a single string, so it's suitable when you want to pass around the joined value as well as when you want to use it for output. To replicate your exact example you'd want to include a newline in your join string. Something like:

```
print('----------\n'.join(mylist))
```

But it's often useful outside prints as well.

An explicit loop would look something like:

```
first = true
for element in mylist:
    if not first:
        print('----------')
    else:
        first = false
    print element
```

Or using `enumerate`:

```
for index, element in enumerate(mylist):
    if index:
        print('----------')
    print element
```

That uses the fact that a numeric type evaluates as false when it equals 0 - `if index != 0:` or `if index > 0:` is logically equivalent here, since we know index will always be a non-`None` and non-negative integer.

Comment: In my 2nd example with the variable "mylist", could you show me how I would accomplish this using join() and/or enumerate?

Comment: `mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`
`x = len(mylist) - 1`

`for i in mylist:
    print(i)
    if not mylist.index(i) == x:
        print('------')`

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `forloop.counter`, or

```
{% if not forloop.first and not forloop.last %}
    <hr>
{% endfor %}
```